# Eclipse can't find class DefaultSolver of OptaPlanner and throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, classpath, optaplanner

Hi I'm building a program using optaplanner, and everything seems to be imported and working fine, but when I run and debug the code, I get a `ClassNotFoundException "org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver"`. I believe I've imported all the jar files correctly, but just to be sure, what jar file is the `DefaultSolver` class in?

As a follow up, I keep getting prompted to edit the source lookup path. This happens after running `SolverConfig.buildSolver() line 156: "DefaultSolver solver = new DefaultSolver();"` I'm running OptaPlanner `6.1.0.Final`.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, I realized that I had both imported the examples jar file into my buildpath and at one point imported a class from the examples jar file when I was messing around with the examples. Rereading the manual I saw it explicitly said not to import the examples jar file, so I unimported that and found the culprit pretty fast. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing the cause and solution:) Still doesn't make sense to me how that can result in that error message though.

Comment: Well I think I actually spoke too soon. Removing that examples jar file let me get further along, I seem to be getting the same symptom as before but with this output message:  

"17:03:19.002 [main] INFO  o.d.c.k.b.impl.KieRepositoryImpl - KieModule was added:MemoryKieModule[ ReleaseId=org.default:artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
17:03:19.128 [main] DEBUG o.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl - Starting Engine in PHREAK mode "

The code also seems to be cycling through possible moves because it's starting up but part of the output for the planning entity is null

Comment: "17:03:19.471 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase -     CH step (0), time spent (226), score (0hard/0soft), selected move count (101), picked move (2014-04-11_B@null => pilot no:0)."

I have never used Maven before and I'm trying to learn how it works now. I created a new maven project and moved my classes over from the old java project and imported all the jar files (I think) as dependencies. Is that OK or should I have just left everything as a java project and import optaplanner as an existing maven project?

Comment: I don't think that's related to this question's issue. As for how to set it up in eclipse, see docs chapter 1.

Comment: I'm new to using Maven, what's the best way to set this up? Have my code in a java project and import classes from optaplanner source in it's own separate maven project? Or use maven for my own code to?

Not sure if this is related to this issue, but I'm running into Java Reflection issues, specifically at org.optaplanner.core.config.util.ConfigUtils, when the code is trying to return a new instance of my move and move filter classes. The error says attached source not found.

Answer (score 0):

Both the class `SolverConfig` and the class `DefaultSolver` are in the jar `optaplanner-core-*.jar`.

So this doesn't make sense: if the jar is in the classpath, it should find `DefaultSolver`. If the jar is not in the classpath, it shouldn't even find `SolverConfig`. What you're seeing can never happen in a normal classpath.

Are you using anything like OSGi, JBoss modules, jigsaw, Karaff or other classloading magic?

Comment: That's what has me completely stumped. I have the JBoss addin for eclipse, is that bad? Also is there a way I can completely reset all classpath information (other than deleting all the imported jars and reimporting them)? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The JBoss addin should be fine. Try debugging and doing SolverConfig.getClass().getPackage().get...() to figure out the actual location of the jar used.

Comment: I tried doing that and manually changing the source when I'm prompted to that jar file. I'm also getting an error message "The source attachment does not contain the source for Throwable.class"

Comment: I fixed the Throwable.class error by linking to the src.zip folder in the jre1.8 folder. Still can't get Eclipse to find DefaultSolver though.

Comment: Start in a clean directly and in Eclipse just import an exist maven project and select the pom.xml file. See docs for instructions. That's been proven to work.